# How can I obliterate the history of a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-drive, sharing

I have a Google Docs document that I want to share, but I don't want to retain the revision history when I do so. What's the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a *very* good question.  Often people in an org can sniff around doc history to see what the author was thinking on earlier revs.

A way around this (not elegant) is to make a copy of the doc using **File** --> **Make a copy...**

This copy will have the most current content and will start history fresh.  Then you can delete the original one, rename the new one, etc.

Comment: That works. It'd be nice if I could just push a button to hide the history, though. Ah well.

Comment: The document doesn't keep the same URL.

Comment: This does not solve the problem if someone else is owner of that document. At this time there is no way to delete the history. Just workarounds.