# How do I share a Google Sheets document and restrict editing to only one column and yet hide the document history from them too?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I have a Google Sheets document that I want to share to many users. However, they must only be able to edit one column. This part seems fine, however, I have numerous other hidden tabs for the purpose of calculations that need to remain hidden (I think I can get this to work by not allowing them to edit these sheets).

The issue arises where I need the history of the document to be hidden as it seems to allow everyone to be able to see all of the background data. Otherwise I will have to resort back to Excel.

Is this another area where Sheets hasn't quite caught up to Excel?

Comment: This is close to a duplicate of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/how-can-i-obliterate-the-history-of-a-google-docs-document. The answer there is the same as what I just said below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're giving them “Edit Access” they will necessarily be able to view the document history, according to the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/VjkR82Ki0dk) and my experience.

If you only need to do this once, before you share, you can work around it:

1. Do all your secret editing and hiding.
2. Copy the sheet to a brand new sheet (optionally delete the old one)
3. Share the new sheet with edit access. It won't have any history.